# How to check status of dailymotion player embedded in iframe?

Tags: javascript, dailymotion-api

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270"
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xwr14q?autoplay=1&mute=1"
allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

and I want to check if the player is currently playing or paused.

Is this possible using iframe or do I have to use the DM.player() method?

Answer (score 1):

To check the status you have to use the JavaScript SDK.

```html
<script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div><button onclick=test_player()>Test Status</button>
    <script>
    var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
        video: "xwr14q",
        width: "50%",
        height: "50%",
        params: {
            autoplay: true,
            mute: true
        }
    });
    function test_player(){
      //true if video is paused
      let status = player.paused;
      alert (status);
    }
</script>
```

For some reason dailymotion refuse the connection on this snippet and the video do not autoplay and do not display controls. However, in my local server, video is played corectly and you can check the status.
For more info see the dopcumentation about the video player here: https://developer.dailymotion.com/player#player-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get this, But what do i do if i want to check the status of the player embedded with iframe?

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot access elements of iframe if are not from the same domain.